# Laravel move Model Save() to inside a method

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-6

Currently I have something like this in my `Controller`:

```
$stock = Stock::first();
$stock->quantity = 10;
$stock->save();
```

I want to change it to something like this, so that the logic is in the `Model`, not in the `Controller` (as I may want to call it from many different places):

```
$stock = Stock::first();
$stock->updateQuantity(10);
```

I have tried adding this to my `Stock` `Model`:

```
public function updateQuantity($quantity){
    $this->quantity = $quantity;
    $this->save();
    return true;
}
```

But it doesn't work, what am I doing wrong?

Comment: Unable to reproduce, works for me

Comment: instead of returning true by default, return `$this->save();` - it will return true if it is saving.

Comment: I can't see reasons it can't work. But, imo, you don't want to use Models to write logic. Models are just the representation of your DB tables. You should use services, and inject the service when you want to use it.

Comment: Might sound silly but have you `dd()` to see whether first is returning you a result in the first place?

Comment: You may want to use `repository` layer. https://designpatternsphp.readthedocs.io/en/latest/More/Repository/README.html